# Add an attribute name without a value using Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to add an attribute to an input field without the value whilst using @Html.TextBoxFor() - notice how the "**data-plugin-datepicker**" name has no value in the code snippet below.

So what I want is this:

```
<input name="DoB" id="DoB" type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
```

By using this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoB, new { @class = "form-control", ??? })
```

Comment: this will help you get part of the way there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515095/526704

Comment: check the this answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/16023943/2907017

Comment: Adding an "empty" attribute, so far as I can tell, is not possible in MVC5 with the built-in helpers except for a few cases where MVC knows to handle it specially (like disabled). It use to be possible by assigning to to an empty string, but at some point that changed.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones - you're right, still it works with an empty string attribute value so I'll resort to that.

Comment: It appears to be working using an empty string in the latest (MVC 5.2.7). Possibly was broken for a while then fixed again?